# What is the difference between SetFixedSize and SetFixedSize used as member access from a QLabel

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qlabel

I'm Struggling to understand what the difference is between setFixedSize used as a function for the widget and using setFixedSize used as the arrow operator from the QLabel.

`

```
    card_front = new QLabel(this);
    setFixedSize(64,96);
    card_front->setFixedSize(64,96);
    card_front->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    card_front->setText("??");
    card_front->show();
```

The reason is when I remove the first setFixedSize, my card does not show on the Qt main window and I'm unsure why.

Comment: You need to add some context -- or preferably a [mcve].  The first `setFixedSize` call is made against the 'current' object: i.e. whatever `this` points to.

Comment: The first one `setFixedSize(64,96);` is called on the parent widget while  `card_front->setFixedSize(64,96);` is called on the `QLabel` child.